Unable to view PNG inline image uploaded in draft email through Microsoft Graph API
Summary:
I am not able to see uploaded PNG files in a draft email on Outlook web using any browser. JPG files work just fine. Also, the files can be viewed using /attachments/{attachment_id}/$value which means they did upload successfully.
Screenshot after uploading:


Detailed steps:

Create a draft email using this endpoint-


POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{mailbox}/messages/

Sample body-
{
    "body": {
        "contentType": "HTML",
        "content": "Hello <br /> <img src=\"cid:image1@example.com\" style=\"max-width:1028px\"> <br /> <br /> <img src=\"cid:image2@example.com\" style=\"max-width:1028px\"> <br /> <br /> <img src=\"cid:image3@example.com\" style=\"max-width:1028px\">"
    },
    "subject": "Re: hello",
    "toRecipients": [
        {
            "emailAddress": {
                "address": "sample@email.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}


Create an upload session to upload a 5mb PNG file-


POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{mailbox}/messages/{draftOutlookId}/attachments/createUploadSession

Body-
{
    "AttachmentItem": {
        "name": "5mb.png",
        "contentType": "image/png",
        "size": 5242880,
        "IsInline": true,
        "ContentId": "image1@example.com"
    }
}


Finally upload the actual file-


PUT {URL FROM ABOVE RESULT}

Headers-
--header 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream'
--header 'Content-Length: 5242880'
--header 'Content-Range: bytes 0-5242879/5242880'

Question:
What should I correct in my approach so that I can view these files?
I was expecting to see these inline images in draft email but the browser is not loading them. Please feel free to try and recreate this issue.
